# SpringBoot public Matchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with this mappging:

```java
@GetMapping(value = {  "/",  })
public String home(Model model) {
}
```

and

- `localhot:8080`,
- `localhost:8080/` ,
- `localhost:8080/.`,
- `localhost:8080/..`

redirects to `/` but not

```
localhost:8080/...
```

and in the `WebSecurityConfig` the only public matcher I have is this one: `/`.

I would like to restrict the access for `localhost:8080/.` and `localhost:8080/..`

here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserSecurityService userSecurityService;
    private final Environment env;

    private static final String SALT = "fd&l23j§sfs23#$1*(_)nof";

    public WebSecurityConfig(UserSecurityService userSecurityService, Environment env) {
        this.userSecurityService = userSecurityService;
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12, new SecureRandom(SALT.getBytes()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        http.addFilterBefore(encodingFilter, CsrfFilter.class);
    
        http.csrf().disable();
    
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicMatchers()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/advertise.html")
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error").permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .key("uniqueAndSecret");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .userDetailsService(userSecurityService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    private String[] publicMatchers() {

        final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
                "/webjars/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/fonts/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/home.html",
                "/links/**",
                "/links.html",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/forgotmypassword.html",
                "/directory/**",
                "/",
                "/error/**/*",
                "/h2-console/**",
                ForgotMyPasswordController.FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL_MAPPING,
                ForgotMyPasswordController.CHANGE_PASSWORD_PATH
        };

        return PUBLIC_MATCHERS;
    }
}
```

Comment: i would say, it is because `.` is alias current directory, `..` is for parent directory,  while `...` stands for resource with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a simple example similar to yours. I am testing with curl (not a web browser) and this is the result:

- `localhost:8080/.`   Internal server error.

This exception is thrown in the server: org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.

- `localhost:8080/..`  Bad request

It seems that the embedded tomcat gives you that response. I tried adding a Global error controller and I could get the error in spring

- `localhost:8080/...` Endpoint not found

This is exepcted as I don't have any mapping for such endpoint "/..."

I think that your browser is actually requesting for `localhost:8080/` when you type `localhost:8080/.` or `localhost:8080/..` Your **spring boot app is not redirecting**